# jQuery center image

Tags: jquery, css

I've got an issue where I was tying to center images using the jQuery Cycle plugin. I found [this](http://old.nabble.com/jquery.cycle-centering-image-td20604074s27240.html) solution, but it wasn't working on single images (there isn't always > 2 images), so I wrote my own little bit of code, which seems to be working, except it sometimes doesn't subtract the height of the image from the height of the div, and so i end up with a margin of 310px.

```
var $image_cnt = $("#images > img").size();
    if($image_cnt < 2) {
        var $single_img = $("#images").children(':first-child');
        var h = $single_img.height();
        $single_img.css({
            marginTop: (620 - h) / 2,
        });
        $(".next").css("display","none");
        $(".prev").css("display","none");
    }
```

I haven't used jQuery much, and just wanted to know if I'd missed something simple, or had written something wrong, which is why the marginTop wasn't playing nice.

Comment: Where is this code running? `document.ready`, `window.load`, or elsewhere?

Comment: I had it running in document.ready ... a friend pointed out that the code was firing to early and changed it to window.load. 

Thanks.

Comment: Good deal, converted this to an answer so we can close some of these 3200 unanswered jQuery questions out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run this in

```
$(window).load(function {
```

So that the images are loaded, running it in `$(document).ready(function {` might execute before the images are ready, and if they're not, their heights will be 0 for the ones not `.complete` yet.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this line:

`var $image_cnt = $("#images > img").size();`

be:

`var $image_cnt = $("#images > img").length();`

olso:

`marginTop: (620 - h) / 2,`

should be:

`marginTop: (620 - h) / 2+'px',`

One more thing you might want to check that each image has a hight set to it... and that the height is in pixels sometimes it could be in percentages, or other units.

hope it helps...